# P-value Granger Causality test

Tags: time-series, statistical-significance, p-value, granger-causality

Is a p value more than 0.05 but less than 0.1 still significant to detect Granger Causality?

It should be, but very often I see people just stop at the 5% significance

EDIt__ And is correct to say that a 10% significance is a WEAKER causality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The p-value threshold of 0.05 is somewhat arbitrary, so you could argue that 0.1 is already significance. It might cause you some raised eyebrows through, mostly because 0.05 is such a widely used threshold.

In practice, a p-value lower than 0.1 but above 0.05 is considered a strong hint towards the alternative hypothesis (causality in this case), but not yet statistically significant.

The way the p-values are presented and how conclusions are drawn based on it is a rather broad discussion and I don't think it matters much which test was used.

Comment: I see. Based on this, being a pvalue of <0.1 just a "strong hit"  and not statisticaly significant, we can safely say that, in this case, it represents a weaker causality. Correct?

Comment: The p-value in itself says little about the measure of causality, or how strong or weak it is. This is expressed by the test-statistic. The p-value respresents the probability of the data happening in the way you found, conditional to the null-hypothesis, so the probability of finding the causality you found, if there was no causality present in the data. So no, you can't say that the causality is weak if the p-value is low. You can be really sure of a weak causality, leaving you with a low p-value.

Comment: Then what are the real life implications of saying that one causality is found at 1% level and the other one at 10%?

Comment: It shows how certain you are of the causality that you found. Very crudely, you could say that at 1%, the chance that the causality that you found was actually not there, is 1%, in contrast to 10%.

Comment: Thanks Jarko for you time :) If I might ask you just one last thing, you mentioned that I could establish the strenght of the causality (or I guess any other hypotheses) looking at the test-statistic. Isn't this value "incorporated" in my p value already? Could you just give me more details?

Comment: By the looks of it, the Granger causality test adds a term causal term to the linear prediction model and compares that to a similar linear model without that term. This comparison of Residual Sum of Squares is done by an F-test, which takes a value near 1 if there is no causality, and deviates from 1 if there is a difference in RSS. This value is then translated to a p-value using the F-distribution. The 'strength' of the causality is expressed in the F-value. If it is close to 1, it's weak, if it is high, the causality has a big effect.